# Получение расстояния между DOM-элементом и началом документа

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Дамы и господа, приветствую. Вопрос заключается в следующем:
подскажите, пожалуйста метод, при помощи которого я смогу получить расстояние между элементом и началом документа.
Что-то похожее на window.pageYOffset.
Чтобы он в цифрах показывал количество пикселей.
P.S. на всякий случай скажу - пробовал и этот метод использовать, но он выдаёт undefined.
Такие вот дела.

Comment: [`element.getBoundingClientRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) показывает все данные о позиции, размерах элемента. `element.getBoundingClientRect().top` думаю именно то что вам нужно.

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое за ответ!

Comment: Вы не знаете, почему в консоль выводятся неверные данные? Делать селектор с переходом на части страницы, к первым нескольким заголовкам скроллит нормально, а до последних недоскролливает. (Как понимаю, каэжый последующий указывает всё меньше и меньше расстояние)

Comment: Вот так на ходу не понятно, что у вас за проблема. Создайте новый вопрос, а я взгляну и напишу если смогу чем то помочь.

Comment: Спасибо! Сейчас создам